Smooth paths at the cusp of $V(x^2 + y^2 - z^3)$
I'm trying to understand how smooth paths on a real algebraic surface are related to its Zariski tangent space.
Consider a "pinched cone" $X = V(x^2 + y^2 - z^3)$. At a regular point $p = (1, 0, 1)$,
we determine that $T_p X$ is cut out by $-2x + 3z = 0$ by the change of variables, and it agrees with the tangent space of $X$ as a smooth manifold (if we set-minus away the singularity). At the point zero however, $T_0 X = \mathbb{R}^3$ (unless I got confused by $\mathbb{R}$ not being algebraically closed and it's actually something else). Obviously $X$ is not even a topological manifold around zero, but still, consider some path $\gamma: I \to X \to \mathbb{R}^3$ that is smooth as a path in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with $\gamma(0) = 0$. For example, $\gamma(t) = (t^3, 0, t^2)$. Intuitively, if we extend $\gamma$ to $\mathbb{R}$, its image should have the tangent line $x = y = 0$ as a tangent line at zero, but obviously that's never going to happen because its corestriction to its image is not a diffeomorphism, and if I understand correctly, the only way to keep it smooth as a path is to force $\dot{\gamma}(0) = 0$, no smooth reparameterization is allowed to change this. A similar argument should work for a generic path of this kind (I think, but I don't know how to check it).
Thus, we have an object $V(x^2 + y^2 - z^3)$ that seems to have three notions of the tangent space at zero, depending on how we squint as it:

$\mathbb{R}^3$, the Zariski tangent space,
$0$, as the space of directional derivatives along smooth paths passing through zero,
$\langle e_z \rangle \cong \mathbb{R}$, as I would have naively drawn it if I knew nothing about geometry beyond grade school.

My question is rather soft: what is the "right" way to think about this tangent space? Is there a bridge between the three versions of it, e.g. some kind of a general construction that specializes to all three under some conditions?
